# Codeigniter + Chrome error (ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG). How to solve?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome

My web application develop using CodeIgniter 1.7 is having error **ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG** when open with Chrome browser only. I tried with all other browser the error will not happen.

I can open the page normally after i refresh the error page. I try search from Google, it seems this bug happen to Chrome user since 2009 until now.

This is my controller code:

```
function search_daily_sales_summary_view()
{
    if(!($this->session->userdata('DAILY_SALES_SUMMARY'))){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You dont have the permission to access that page.');
        redirect('login/home');
    }

    $this->load->model('currency_model');
    $this->load->model('bill_model');

    $data = array();

    $report = array();

    if($query = $this->currency_model->list_currency())
    {
        foreach ($query as $row) {

        $currencyid = $row->CURRENCY_ID;
        $currencycode = $row->CURRENCY_CODE;

        if($buyData = $this->bill_model->calculate_buy($currencyid))
        {
            $totalbuy = $buyData->total_from_amount;
            $totalbuy_rate = $buyData->rate;

            if($buyData->total_from_amount=='')
            {
                $totalbuy = 0.00;
            }

            if($buyData->rate=='')
            {
                $totalbuy_rate = 0.00;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $totalbuy = 0.00;
            $totalbuy_rate = 0.00;
        }

        if($sellData = $this->bill_model->calculate_sell($currencyid))
        {
            $totalsell = $sellData->total_from_amount;
            $totalsell_rate = $sellData->rate;

            if($sellData->total_from_amount=='')
            {
                $totalsell = 0.00;
            }

            if($sellData->rate=='')
            {
                $totalsell_rate = 0.00;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $totalsell = 0.00;
            $totalsell_rate = 0.00;
        }

        $report[] = array("currency"=>$currencycode, "buy"=>$totalbuy, "buyrate"=>$totalbuy_rate, "sell"=>$totalsell, "sellrate"=>$totalsell_rate);

        }

        $data['records'] = $report;

    }

    $this->load->model('company_model');
    if($query = $this->company_model->list_company())
    {
        $data['company_list'] = $query;
    }

    $this->load->model('branch_model');
    if($this->input->post('company'))
    {
        $companyid = $this->input->post('company');

        if($query = $this->branch_model->view_company_branch($companyid))
        {
            $data['branch_list'] = $query;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($query = $this->branch_model->list_branch())
        {
            $data['branch_list'] = $query;
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('report/daily_sales_summary', $data);

}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: That's an interesting one. Have you tried looking at the headers to see why (or if) they're so big? This is easy with curl: `curl -I http://you_url_here/`

Comment: I use the code and here is the output that i get: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/Z5F  Take note that even if there is no data (means i search for non exist data), the error will still happen.

Comment: Oh, that's a redirect. We have to make curl follow redirects. Try it again with the `-L` option: `curl -I -L http://your_url_here/`

Comment: Ok i follow your instruction and here is the output : http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/Z5J

Comment: It looks like curl is being redirected to the login page (because it's not logged in). You might try instead using Firebug or Web Inspector to look at the headers. Some of the Chrome bug reports suggest that this is a result of trying to store large objects in a CodeIgniter session. You should think about the things you're using CI's sessions for and if you should instead be storing that data in your models.

Comment: thanks. in the end i end up completely removed all the session in my model function that i used for this controller and the problem now gone. looks like i need to find other way to store search variable for this one.

Comment: also... shouldn't if(!($this->session->userdata('DAILY_SALES_SUMMARY'))) be if(!$this->session->userdata('DAILY_SALES_SUMMARY')){

Answer (score 2):

CI stores sessions in a cookie. If you store too much in a cookie, you get errors.

Set CodeIgniter to use DB sessions instead, or save this to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Saving Session Data to a Database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

> Note: By default the table is called ci_sessions, but you can name it
>   anything you want as long as you update the
>   application/config/config.php file so that it contains the name you
>   have chosen. Once you have created your database table you can enable
>   the database option in your config.php file as follows:

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

Once enabled, the Session class will store session data in the DB.

Make sure you've specified the table name in your config file as well:

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Note: The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do it.