# ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG error in chrome . How to solve it?

Tags: codeigniter, google-chrome

I'm using codeigniter for my project in chrome browser i'm facing the following error in some pages .

Error : ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG

Comment: Have you tried as suggested there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260503/codeigniter-chrome-error-err-response-headers-too-big-how-to-solve

Comment: i used existing solution but facing same problem . If there any other solution please help me.

Comment: Is the same problem exist with core php as well or it is only in codeigniter

Comment: i'm using codeigniter dont know about core.

Comment: By core php i mean simple php script without using any framework

Comment: im using codeigniter framework.